# Por que meu display - flex não está funcionando?

Tags: css, flexbox

o código HTML é este aqui- Queria colocar um display flex apenas no "forms2" para os inputs ficarem em row. Oque devo fazer?

```
    <div class="forms1">
        <div class="prontuario"><b>Prontuário:</b> <input type="text"></div>
    </div><!--forms1-->
        
    <div class="forms2">
           <ul>
                <li><b>Nome:</b> <input type="text"></div></li>
                <li><b>CPF:</b> <input type="text"></div></li>
                <li><b>ENDEREÇO:</b> <input type="text"></div></li>
            </ul>
    </div><!--forms2-->
```

*CSS
.forms2{
display: flex;
}

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler  [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro você precisa arrumar a estrutura html, você tem um monte de divs fechando sem abertura nas LIs. Depois você precisa aplicar o estilo na ul e não na div.

```
    <div>
    <ul class="forms2">
        <li><b>Nome:</b> <input type="text" /></li>
        <li><b>CPF:</b> <input type="text" /></li>
        <li><b>ENDEREÇO:</b> <input type="text" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

E agora aplicar o estilo

```
.forms2 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Comment: @Thiernodia se funcionou seria interessante marcar a resposta como correta (: